# GMAPS API V3 Custom InfoWindow: static position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I really want to know if there's a way to make the `InfoWindow` display on the center of the screen and not above the marker.

Also, how can I get rid of that predefined crappy speech bubble style of the window itself?

When the marker gets clicked, the `InfoWindow` shall be displayed in the center of the screen with a width of `720px`, a black opaque background and a little content (no speech bubble, no pan, just pure css). I cant find anything coming close to what I need.

I included the `infobox.js` to try to get what I want, but I got 2 problems with this:

1. It doesn't take my position: absolute and the given top/left values.
2. After closing the `InfoBox` once, it won't open again.

Some code that could be relevant:

```
// creating the box

var ib'.$counter.' = new InfoBox(myOptions);

// box options - just the style part

var myOptions = { boxStyle: { ,width: "720px" ,position:"absolute" ,top:
    "-100px" ,left: "100" } };

// add listener - plane js

google.maps.event.addListener(marker'.$counter.', "click",
function() { ib'.$counter.'.show() });
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Best regards,
Rellston.